# Android save downloaded data to SD

Tags: android, sd-card

I've developed an app which 
- download some data ( .png and .wav files )
- insert the path where each files is downloaded into a database (SQLite)

So far so good, everything works.
Some users asked me if there was a way to move the the downloaded data in the sd card in order to save some internal space.

By now i create the directory with this line of code

```
File directory = getApplicationContext().getDir("folderName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Then the app will fill it with all the stuff I downloaded.

I tried using this piece of code:

```
                try {
                File newFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TestFolder");
                if (!newFolder.exists()) {
                    newFolder.mkdir();
                }
                try {
                    File file = new File(newFolder, "MyTest" + ".txt");
                    file.createNewFile();
                    System.out.println("Path: " + file.getPath());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("ex: " + ex);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("e: " + e);
            }
```

And this create a folder and a text file into: /storage/emulated/0/TestFolder/MyTest.txt
Which is not my sdcard directory, it should be:
/storage/sdcard1/TestFolder/MyTest.txt

So my question is:
- where and how I saved my app's private data (.png and .wav files) in the SD card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getExternalFilesDir`, `getExternalStorageDirectory` or relatives, does not always return a folder on a SD card. On my Samsung for example, it returns an emulated, internal SD card.

You can get all external storage devices (also the removable) using [`ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getExternalFilesDirs(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)).

My next step, is to use the folder on the device with the largest free space. To get that, I enumerate the `getExternalFilesDirs`, and call `getUsableSpace` on every folder.

I use this code to store (cache) bitmaps in a folder named "bmp" on the device.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("ResultOfMethodCallIgnored")
    private static File[] allCacheFolders(Context context) {
        File local = context.getCacheDir();
        File[] extern = ContextCompat.getExternalCacheDirs(context);

        List<File> result = new ArrayList<>(extern.length + 1);

        File localFile = new File(local, "bmp");
        localFile.mkdirs();
        result.add(localFile);

        for (File anExtern : extern) {
            if (anExtern == null) {
                continue;
            }
            try {
                File externFile = new File(anExtern, "bmp");
                externFile.mkdirs();
                result.add(externFile);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // Probably read-only device, not good for cache -> ignore
            }
        }
        return result.toArray(new File[result.size()]);
    }



    private static File _cachedCacheFolderWithMaxFreeSpace;
    private static File getCacheFolderWithMaxFreeSpace(Context context) {
        if (_cachedCacheFolderWithMaxFreeSpace != null) {
            return _cachedCacheFolderWithMaxFreeSpace;
        }
        File result = null;
        long free = 0;
        for (File folder : allCacheFolders(context)) {
            if (!folder.canWrite()) {
                continue;
            }
            long currentFree = folder.getUsableSpace();
            if (currentFree < free) {
                continue;
            }
            free = currentFree;
            result = folder;
        }
        _cachedCacheFolderWithMaxFreeSpace = result;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: "The getExternalStorageDirectory does not always return a folder on a SD card" -- more accurately, it always returns the root of [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). External storage is almost never removable on modern Android devices.

Comment: "does not always return a folder on a SD card" this is because the Android Docs say (about the [`getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29)) `Traditionally this is an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be mounted as a filesystem on a computer.`

Comment: I did some test:
Motorola MotoG 2nd generation with Android 5.0.2 and sd card return: /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/mypackage/cache/bmp 

Asus Nexus7 with Android 6.0 and NO sd card return: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.vesco.personaggi2/cache/bmp

What you wrote it's kinda brilliant, man.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/newfolder");
dir.mkdirs();
```

add permission in Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: that line of code create a folder in /storage/emulated/0

Comment: on which phone are you testing

Comment: Motorola MotoG 2nd generation with  Android 5.0.2